# how to use decorators in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator

I have some problem. i dont understand how to use decorators in my project. May be someone can help me?

## personal_information.html.slim

```
    td.word-break.hidden-value = "*******#{form.dot_application.driver_applicant.ssn.last(4)}"
    td.word-break
      button.show-hidden-info data-field-type="ssn" data-link="#{company_dot_application_show_hidden_informations_path(@dot_application)}"
        | Show SSN
```

## driver_apllicant_decorator.rb

```
def mask_string(value)
  case value
    when 'ssn'
      "*******#{form.dot_application.driver_applicant.ssn.last(4)}"
    when 'dob'
      "*******#{form.dot_application.driver_applicant.date_of_birth.last(4)}"
    else
      render 403
  end
end
```

And i dont understand how to use decorator in my views in

```
td.word-break.hidden-value = "*******# {form.dot_application.driver_applicant.ssn.last(4)}"
```

How to refactor the  code for render "****1234" right with use decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of a decorator is simply to "extend the model" with presentation methods, for use in views - either by [directly calling `object`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#accessing-the-model), or [delegating methods](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#delegating-methods). A decorator does not perform controller actions, like `render 403`; that is not its job.

For instance, you could write this decorator as:

```
class DriverApplicantDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def masked_ssn
    mask_string(object.ssn)
  end

  def masked_date_of_birth
    mask_string(object.date_of_birth)
  end

  private

  def mask_string(value)
    "*******#{value.last(4)}"
  end
end
```

In your view, you can then simply call these methods - so long as you are [referencing the *decorated* model](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#when-to-decorate-objects).

For example, this could be:

```
td.word-break.hidden-value= form.dot_application.driver_applicant.decorate.masked_ssn
```

(Or elsewhere, as per the above link, you may not need to explicitly call `decorate` in the view like that.)

Comment: Thx very much for answer. I'll try soon and giving feedback.

Comment: Thx very much again. You are the god a programmer. I readed 2hour infos, but dont understand good how it should be work. And you solved my problem:) Good luck